# how to use mercurial and svn together

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

The SVN repo at work is only reachable internally (at least for me as contractor). When not at work, I would like to use HG and then sync with SVN the next day.

Is it at all advisable to use both? Are there issues one should be aware of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Working With Subversion](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) page on the mercurial wiki includes a few different, suitable workflows for just what you're describing.

Comment: that's a great overview, thank you. i guess, hgsubversion is the way to go as it seems to offer a real bridge. I was thinking much more naive - just shove the checked out project into a new hg repo, add the ignores for svn and hg to be oblivious of each other and check the changes made locally to svn later. but there are obviously many downsides to that

Comment: I just wanted a local repository where I can try stuff out using the benefits of hg. But I don't want to accidentally affect any of work's core svn (hgsubversion might not be entirely reliable) so the naive approach appeals. What downsides can you see?